# Paho Mqtt client does not fetch data after third or fourth times related fragment opens

Tags: android, android-fragments, mqtt

I am using mqtt paho android client and fetching data in a fragment without problem. After navigating to another fragments 3. or 4. times from that fragment and being back to  that fragment, data does not come from cloud server. How can I handle this problem? I do not make any operation on life cycle functions like onResume onPause etc.

```
public class PFragment extends Fragment {

View view;
private final MemoryPersistence persistence = new MemoryPersistence();
MqttAndroidClient client;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_plant, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    connect();
    openGame();
    openStats();

    return view;
}

private void openGame() {
    game.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame, new GameFragment(), "fragment_settings")
                    .setTransitionStyle(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
                    .addToBackStack("game")
                    .commit();
        }
    });
}

private void openStats() {
    stats.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame, new StatsFragment(), "fragment_settings")
                    .setTransitionStyle(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
                    .addToBackStack("stats")
                    .commit();
        }
    });
}

private void disconnect() {
    try {
        client.disconnect();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    client.unregisterResources();
}

public void connect() {

    String clientId = MqttAsyncClient.generateClientId();
    client = new MqttAndroidClient(getActivity(), "mqtturl",
            clientId, persistence);


    MqttConnectOptions mqttConnectOptions = new MqttConnectOptions();
    mqttConnectOptions.setMqttVersion(MqttConnectOptions.MQTT_VERSION_3_1);
    mqttConnectOptions.setUserName("xx");
    mqttConnectOptions.setPassword("xx".toCharArray());
    mqttConnectOptions.setCleanSession(true);



    try {
        client.connect(mqttConnectOptions, null, new IMqttActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                Log.i("a", "Connection Success!");
                try {

                    client.subscribe("x", 0);

                    water.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            try {
                                if (a.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("push")) {
                                    client.publish("a", new MqttMessage("1".getBytes()));

                                } else if (water_me_text.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("pull")) {

                                    client.publish("a", new MqttMessage("0".getBytes()));


                                }
                            } catch (MqttException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                } catch (MqttException ex) {

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {

            }
        });
    } catch (MqttException ex) {
        L
    }


    client.setCallback(new MqttCallback() {
        @Override
        public void connectionLost(Throwable cause) {


        }

        @Override
        public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
            if (topic.equals("x")) {

            }

            checkPlantStatus("Amaryllis");
        }

        @Override
        public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken token) {
        }
    });





}
```

}

Comment: Please always share your code.

Comment: Seems that you are creating the connection every time the view is created which in turn is creating duplicate connections and finally your MQTT connection is giving up on it. Kindly share the code so that I can look further into it.

Comment: @HuzefaGadi added